# process::Command not running a program being provided

Tags: rust, cmd

I'm trying to run a program through rust to make a sort of selection GUI. I'm 90% sure that I've gotten my working directory correct but actually running the test command is not doing anything. I've followed the documentation the best I could, but I'm pretty new.

```
use std::process::Command;
use std::path::Path;
use std::env;

const ROM_DIRECTORY: &str = "C:/ROMS";

fn main() {
    let internal_directory = Path::new(ROM_DIRECTORY);
    assert!(env::set_current_dir(internal_directory).is_ok());
    println!("Successfully changed working directory to {}!", internal_directory.display());

    Command::new("Rockman.nes");
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating `Command` object by itself will not do anything. You must explicitly execute it. You can do it by calling methods like [output](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.output), [spawn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.spawn) or [status](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.status).

Comment: ```
Command::new("Rockman.nes")
                .spawn()
                .expect("Failed to open ROM.");
```

This throws the error of "program not found" + my .expect, does this mean the directory didn't change and couldn't find the .nes file?